# In Typescript, How do I call a class with using a variable for the class name

Tags: javascript, typescript, class

Edit: the suggested answer in private feedback is from 2013 with the latest answers 2018. I tried the examples in typescript playground and they error, so they may be out of date:

I am trying to create a class object by first getting the class name in a variable, then calling it via `new`.
i.e. instead of calling new `ActualClassName`, `ActualClasName` is stored in a variable `x`. So I want to call `new x`
I am not sure this is even the right approach, but I need something close to this functionality.
See the below commented code. the error is at the bottom (expression not constructable)

```
    /// associat class names with formId /////
const formNames = {
  form1: "F1",
  form2: "F2",
};
/// retrieve the name of class, returns a string ///
let formConstructor = formNames["form1"]; // returns f1

/////// define classes
class F1 {
  private payload: object;
  constructor(payload: object) {
    this.payload = payload;
  }
  myMethod(): string {
    return "I have called the F1.myMethod()";
  }
}
class f2 {
  private payload: object;
  constructor(payload: object) {
    this.payload = payload;
  }
  myMethod(): string {
    return "I have called the F2.myMethod()";
  }
}
/////////// expression not constructable.
let payload = {}
let form = new formConstructor(payload);  //How do create new class instance from this ?????
form.myMethod()
```

Comment: Question, why do you use *strings* for the classes? What is the benefit over having `const formNames = { form1: F1, form2: F2, };`? Is this [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)? Because if you just not use strings you can do `new formNames["form1"](payload)`

Comment: @VLAZ That fixed it. I had used strings to get past some errors and I got stuck with something that would never have worked.
Followed your suggestion. I also had to declare the classes before the const formNames but it all works.